# Purpose of Bootstrap HTML 62.5%

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

The following code from the Twitter Bootstrap CSS:

```
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

reduces all my page fonts (specified in CSS as, e.g., font-size: .85em) by 65%.

What is the purpose of Bootstrap reducing all font sizes to 65%?  What is a good practice to override this?

Comment: font-size: 62.5% is pretty much an industrial standard nowadays and isn't specifically for bootstrap. It's in case someone has increased their font size in their browser settings. I believe that hardcoding a 10px font size on the body would override that browser setting. So it's deference to usability using a percentage rather than a hard-coded value.

Comment: @KevinVoorn  Thank you for the explanation.  I didn't know about this standard.  And I prefer not to set the font size to absolute value of 10 or more px. Setting the size to fraction of .em I thought is more flexible approach. I will have to review this.

Comment: It makes it easier to to REM font sizing. Checkout this: http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem

Comment: @ScottSimpson  Thank you. I will follow the link.

Answer (score 0):

That's not in the default bootstrap css

https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css

```
html{
  font-family:sans-serif;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust:100%
}
```

Comment: Joe, I got the setting from the Chrome Developer tools and my copy of the Bootstrap 3. Maybe my copy is not up-to-date. Could it be that Bootstrap changed this value from version 3 to 3.3?
Thank you

Comment: Could be...I've only got as far back as 3.2.0 That would be highly annoying if it was in there!

Comment: @Hidalgo Your version was not the default in version 3.0.0 or 3.0.1. https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.css

Comment: @KevinVoorn  I opened the .css  in your link and I see the HTML { font-size: 62.5% }